# Linking a GPL executable from proprietary .bat script

Tags: licensing, gpl, linking

Licensing question - am I allowed to use a GPL binary executable (.exe) in my copyrighted .bat script? Namely I want to use FART command line tool (find & replace text in files) in an install script for a proprietary product. Is such use actually static or dynamic type of linking?

Comment: If you're just calling an executable from a batch script, that's not linking; it's execution.

Comment: could the bat work without the FART or can BURP (Big Ugly Replace Program) drop in just as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bat files execute and do not link.

Yes you can execute GPLed code from non-GPLed code. The only thing you will need to do is if you distribute FART, make sure you distribute it's source code as well. See semantic A/V for a popular example. Or many video games.  As long as you give credit and don't violate the rules about distributing binaries without source your should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Is it enough to distribute only URL to the source code?

Comment: Usually, so long as it's the correct URL